# Find unsorted indices after using numpy.searchsorted

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search, numpy

I have a large (millions) array of ID numbers `ids`, and I want to find the indices where another array of targets (`targets`) exist in the `ids` array.  For example, if

```
ids = [22, 5, 4, 0, 100]
targets = [5, 0]
```

then I want the result:

```
>>> [1,3]
```

If I pre-sort the array of `ids`, then it's easy to find matches using `numpy.searchsorted`, e.g.

```
>>> ids = np.array([22, 5, 4, 0, 100])
>>> targets = [5, 0]
>>> sort = np.argsort(ids)
>>> ids[sort]
[0,4,5,22,100]
>>> np.searchsorted(ids, targets, sorter=sort)
[2,0]
```

But how can I find the *reverse* mapping to 'unsort' this result?  I.e. to map the sorted entries at `[2,0]` back to where they were before: `[1,3]`.

Comment: Your code only worked for me when I used `ids = np.array([22, 5, 4, 0, 100])` for line 1.

Comment: Actually it fails,for me, at `ids[sort]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few answers dancing around this already, but just to make it clear all you need to do is use `sort[rank]`.

```
# Setup
ids = np.array([22, 5, 4, 0, 100])
targets = np.array([5, 0])

sort = np.argsort(ids)
rank = np.searchsorted(ids, targets, sorter=sort)
print(sort[rank])
# array([1, 3])
```

Comment: Not that it really matters, but Is this not the same as my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Could you just do this?

```
sort[np.searchsorted(ids, targets, sorter=sort)]
```

Alternatively:

```
np.hstack([np.where(ids==x)[0] for x in targets])
```

both give:

```
array([1, 3])
```

Comment: This does work, but it's the same as just searching value by value --- which will be very slow

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come up with something.

We can construct a 'cipher' or sorts: `key = numpy.arange(len(ids))` applying the initial sorter to this key then gives the reverse mapping: `revsort = key[np.argsort(ids)]`

---

edit: as @birico points out, `key[sort]` is identical to `sort` itself!

```
>>> sort = np.argsort(ids)
>>> ids[sort]
[0,4,5,22,100]
>>> found = np.searchsorted(ids, targets, sorter=sort)
>>> found
[2,0]
>>> sort[found]
[1,3]
```

Comment: `key[sort]` will always be exactly the same as `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) here for a one-liner -

```
_,out = np.where(np.array(ids)==np.array(targets)[:,None])
```

Sample run -

```
In [20]: ids
Out[20]: [22, 5, 4, 0, 100]

In [21]: targets
Out[21]: [0, 22, 5]

In [22]: _,out = np.where(np.array(ids)==np.array(targets)[:,None])

In [23]: out
Out[23]: array([3, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work.  If you reverse `targets`, you still get `[1,3]` out; you're not using the ordering info.  IOW, you get *participating* indices, not *corresponding* indices.

Comment: @DSM Ah yes, the order info would be lost.

Comment: @DSM Added new approach with `broadcasting`.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I doesn't this amount to the same thing as @atomh33ls suggested ---- it still ends up doing a search value by value right?

Comment: @zhermes Well I think with broadcasting I am avoiding the loop used in that other answer.

Comment: @Divakar sure, there's no explicit loop, but won't the speed be basically the same as a loop?  And memory usage a little worse?

Comment: @zhermes Not sure about the speed, but memory would be needed  a bit more.